# What is the theory foundation of the binary encoding of data digits into an EAN-13 barcode?

Tags: coding-theory, encoding-scheme

In the Wikipedia, there is explanation about [EAN-13 and several table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Article_Number_(EAN)), which are called "Structure of EAN-13" and "Encoding of the digits", but I did not know what theory  the contents of the two table are based? For example, in "Structure of EAN-13",  0 correspondings to LLLLLL and RRRRRR, but in "Encoding of digits", 0 corresponds to 0001101, 0100111 and 1110010. Why or what am I missing ?

Comment: I don't think this on topic for CS.se. Also, I'm not sure what your question really is. There's no theory behind the barcode, it's just an encoding scheme. The wikipedia article explains everything. The first digit determines which codes are used for the next 6 digits (L or G), the last six are always R codes, and the digit encoding tells you what each digit becomes (a 0 means no vertical line, a 1 means a line). Try looking at the pictures in that section.

Comment: @LukeMathieson， thank you! You are right, "it's just an encoding scheme, and The first digit determines which codes are used for the next 6 digits (L or G)", But this scheme has no logic theory? `I am so sorry to ask such a question like this, because I don't know where to ask this! `

Comment: @abelard2008 Never hurts to ask! :) There's some basic error detection using the checksum (mentioned at the top of the wikipedia article), but nothing deep or particularly clever.

Comment: may this will help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Product_Code

Comment: One legitimate question is: what were the guiding principles behind the development of the code?